# extraer datos de una tabla, con parámetros en otra en MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Buenas tardes a todos. Necesito su ayuda en el siguiente problema:

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL, la cual tiene una tabla con mas de 100.000 registros. Son varias columnas (cerca de 30) de información, una de ellas el `Cod_Cliente`. Luego, se importan datos a una tabla en blanco, donde tiene unas 5 columnas, una de ellas tambien `Cod_Cliente`. Esta tabla tiene unos 5.000 registros.

Necesito hacer lo siguiente:
Una vez cargada la tabla en blanco, con los 5,000 registros, se corra un proceso para buscar cada fila de esta tabla, buscar el mismo `Cod_cliente` en la tabla de 100.000 registros, y se llene una tercera tabla donde se unan columnas de una y de la otra.

El campo `Cod_Cliente` tiene datos únicos, de cada uno de los 100.000 clientes. En ambas tablas es único

Alguien me puede dar una mano, por favor?

Gracias

Comment: Cod_cliente es unico?

Comment: Si, es el unico que tiene datos únicos, de cada uno de los 100.000 clientes. En ambas tablas es único.

Comment: @Gonzalo Parece que tienes buenas respuestas ya, así que voy a salirme un poco del tema ¿para qué quieres esa nueva tabla? Por la definición en la pregunta, casi diría que lo que necesitas es una vista

Comment: A ver, te explico. Todo lo que se hace con esta información, se la hace en excel. Se la está ahora migrando a MySQL. La tabla grande, lleva todos los datos de los clientes, incluyendo direcciones, datos de facturación, fecha en que fueron creados, etc. Es una tabla plana, por lo que llevan en realidad casi 90 columnas. De esa, salvé como importantes realmente unas 30. Cada fin de mes, se descarga en excel una tabla con mas o menos 5000 clientes activos, que hayan generado movimiento, y que llevan ahora una columna que se llama monto_consumido.

Comment: Lo que estamos haciendo es, una vez importada esa tabla excel a MySQL, buscar cada cliente en la tabla de 5000, y buscar su correspondiente info en la tabla "maestra" de 100.000, donde están todos los clientes. Esta info cruzada, se guarda en otra tabla, con una estructura mucho mas simple y estructurada, donde ya se hace todo lo necesario para facturar los movimientos del mes. No se trabajarán en la tabla de 100.000 ni en la de 5.000, sino solo en la que se ha generado de la unión de las otras dos, gracias a los JOINS explicados en la respuesta

Comment: No se que onda por lo tanto considero que es un catastrofe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza un `INNER JOIN` para unir las filas necesarias de ambas tablas. Para insertar en una tabla, puedes utilizar `INSERT INTO` de la siguiente manera:

```sql
INSERT INTO T3 (COD_CLIENTE, <otras columnas)
SELECT T1.COD_CLIENTE, <columnas con valores>
FROM Tabla1 T1
    INNER JOIN Tabla2 T2 ON T2.COD_CLIENTE = T1.COD_CLIENTE
WHERE
    -- quizás necesites otras condiciones
    -- si no tienes ninguna condición adicional, elimina la cláusula WHERE
```

Se considera buena práctica indicar las columnas y el orden en el que la información se debe insertar. Esto por si la tabla en un futuro cambia su estructura.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esto es exactamente lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 3):

Podrias unir ambas tablas usando un `INNER JOIN` si es que buscas coincidencias
entre ambas

[SQL INNER JOIN Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

o `LEFT JOIN` o `RIGTH JOIN` si buscas obtener los registros de una tabla sin importar si tienen relaciones con la segunda

[SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

en tu caso seria

```
SELECT T5.campo1, T5.campo2, T10.campo1 as campoT10 
FROM Tabla5MIL T5 
INNER JOIN Tabla10MIL T10 ON T5.Cod_Cliente = T10.Cod_Cliente
```

El resultado de la query podrias insertarlo en la otra tabla mediante el

[SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias.